# SQL in VBA right join with no data from first table

Tags: sql, excel, vba, join

I try to join data from multiple workbooks and use it in current workbook instead of VLOOKUP function. So I do not want return key column, just those that match criteria in key column in current workbook.

I got "Syntax error in FROM clause."

Everything works fine without "RIGHT JOIN" part. I use ADO.

```
    "SELECT t1.number " & _
    "FROM" & _
        "(SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] " & _
        "IN '" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Src1.xlsm' " & _
        "[Excel 12.0;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Mode=Read;Extended Properties='HDR=YES;'] " & _
        "UNION ALL " & _
        "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] " & _
        "IN '" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Src2.xlsb' " & _
        "[Excel 12.0;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Mode=Read;Extended Properties='HDR=YES;']" & _
        "UNION ALL " & _
        "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] " & _
        "IN '" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Src2.xlsb' " & _
        "[Excel 12.0;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Mode=Read;Extended Properties='HDR=YES;']) t1" & _
    "RIGHT JOIN [Sheet1$] " & _
        "IN '" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "' " & _
        "[Excel 12.0;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Mode=Read;Extended Properties='HDR=YES;'] t2 ON t2.key = t1.key;"
```

Data looks like

ThisWorkbook.Fullname:

```
key | someColumns | number 
k1  | somedata    |
k3  | somedata    |
k5  | somedata    |
```

\Src1.xlsm (also Src2):

```
key | number
k1  | 15
k2  | 11
k3  | 8
k4  | 16
k5  | 7
```

Likely result in Thisworkbook.fullname

```
key | someColumns | number 
k1  | somedata    | 15
k3  | somedata    | 8
k5  | somedata    | 7
```

Comment: Space  need.  Properties='HDR=YES;']" &  to  Properties='HDR=YES;']  " &

Comment: Properties='HDR=YES;']) t1"  to  Properties='HDR=YES;']) as t1   "

Comment: "RIGHT JOIN ( select * from [Sheet1$] " & _
        "IN '" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "' " & _
        "[Excel 12.0;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Mode=Read;Extended Properties='HDR=YES;']) as t2 ON t2.key = t1.key;"

Comment: Thank you, but does not really work. Works with you? http://prntscr.com/lrioc0

Comment: I have not computer. I only advice where you were mistaken.

Comment: I think  your select clause is not correct too.  And it is fit  to use 
where clause than right join.

Comment: have you tried your query in MS query? this might be a help for yourself to debug your sql

Comment: Code without RIGHT JOIN works perfectly and I dont need to use WHERE (If you mean it like filter). Actually I have no experience with that kind of debugging (I dont use SQL very often), so I can not help myself within reasonable time.

Comment: `Number` is a reserved word and cause issues in queries. You can try to wrap it in parenthesis: `t1.[number]`

Comment: "number" actually is not used in real query, just this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim Rs As Object
Sub getRs(strSQL As String)
    Dim strConn As String
    Dim i As Integer

    strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"

    Set Rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Rs.Open strSQL, strConn

End Sub
Sub test()
    Dim strQuery As String

   strQuery = "SELECT t1.number " & _
    "FROM [Sheet1$] as t2 LEFT JOIN " & _
        "(SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] " & _
        "IN '" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Src1.xlsm' " & _
        "[Excel 12.0;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Mode=Read;Extended Properties='HDR=YES;'] " & _
        "UNION ALL " & _
        "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] " & _
        "IN '" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Src2.xlsb' " & _
        "[Excel 12.0;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Mode=Read;Extended Properties='HDR=YES;']) as t1 " & _
        "ON t1.key = t2.key Where not isnull(t2.key) "


    getRs strQuery
    Range("c2").CopyFromRecordset Rs
    Rs.Close
    Set Rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Works great. After all I realized there were some missing spaces in my code, but this looks better. I will use it. Thank you.

Comment: One more thing. How would I check if field "key" is unique? If not, do not copy from recordset. I tried approach that rs.Fields(0) is array, but does not work.